# UIButton does not change background on touchUpInside

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have some custom type UIButtons placed pragmatically in a custom view. The view is basically a menu. I am generating the buttons with the following code, inside the view's .m file:

```
-(void) generateButtons: (NSMutableArray *) buttonsArray
{
   UIImage *barItemImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-menubar-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

   float buttonWidth = (self.frame.size.width - (2 * FIRSTBUTTONXCOORDINATE) - 25)/ 6.0f;
   float xCoord = FIRSTBUTTONXCOORDINATE;
   float yCoord = (self.frame.size.height - BUTTONHEIGHT) / 2.0f;
   for (int i = 0; i < buttonsArray.count; i++)
   {
       NSString* buttonTitle = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(botButtonAction:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

       [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       button.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, buttonWidth, BUTTONHEIGHT);
       button.tag = i;
       [button setBackgroundImage:barItemImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       xCoord += buttonWidth + 5;
       [self addSubview:button];
   }
}
```

On touchUpInside, botButtonAction is called and it does what it is supposed to. However, the buttons do not usually give any visual indication of the touchUpInside. When I **touchDown** on a button and swipe in any direction, then I see the background color get darker. Sometimes, I see the same visual indication on touchUpInside. It seems completely random though.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Edit: Sorry, I got occupied with other issues. Here is the code for botButtonAction and the method it calls

```
-(void) botButtonAction: (UIButton *) sender
{
 if (self.delegate)
    [self.delegate optionsMenuAction:self data:sender.tag];
}

 -(void)optionsMenuAction:(OptionsMenueView *)view data:(int)tag
 {
     if (self.PDFVC)
     {
         [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:YES];
     }

     if (!self.optionsMenue.isAtWPC || tag != WPC)
         [self transitionFromViewAtIndex:self.selectedVCIndex toView:tag];

    else
         [self transitionFromViewAtIndex:self.selectedVCIndex toView:WPList];
}
```

But since I am using touchUpInside, these methods don't get called on touchDown. I just want the button to be highLight (grayout the bg a little) on touchDown. As I state before, that happens on touchDown and swipe.

**Edit**
I had so far been running this on actual devices (iPad air and iPad 2). When I tried running it on the simulator, I get the correct result. On mouse click, the button gets highlighted.

**Edit**
I think I figured out the exact problem (still looking for a solution). If I touchDown precisely on the button and the touch does not cover any part of the insets, then the highlighting works. However, if the touch covers part of the button and also part of the insets/outside, then the highlighting doesn't work.

Comment: It is a bit hard to say without seeing what happens in `botButtonAction:`. Could you provide that section? Also, just to double check, you do realize `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is called when the user lifts his/her finger, right?

Comment: hello user2891327 can you post code of botButtonAction:

Answer (score 1):

add this line:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:HighlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in botButtonAction:

```
-(void)botButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some iamge.png"] 
                                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

or use the code below code in for loop

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_press.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

or if you want to give some color then setcolour of button

Comment: I want the button to be highlighted before botButtonAction is called (on touchDown).

Comment: use this code [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_press.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted]; it will show image(selected image when you tap on it).but as you remove finger from button it change to normal image

Answer (score 0):

change the title colour when tap on the button like this

```
[yourButon setTitleColor:[UIColor colorYouWant] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

hope this will help you......

Comment: Surprisingly, this does not have any effect either.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at some point too. These other answers will give you the result you seek normally. However.... You are using [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom].. Which is really buggy if you do not alloc/init the UIButton.. Try changing this line to a normal button allocation and then add the following lines of the answers in this post. This should work for you.

So in short,

replace `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`
with `[[UIButton alloc] init];`

And then add the following changes to your code to change the image.

```
[myNewlyAllocatedButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_press.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Still nothing. I changed the code to alloc init and everything still works the same.

Comment: If you change the colour of the button on the touchupinside event. Does the button change to that colour?

Comment: Could you please take a look at my latest edit. I think I need to somehow make the area of the button for touch larger.